# Closure of an open Ball

Tags: general-topology

We know that the closure of an open ball is a subset of a closed ball.

$U_{\varepsilon}(x):= \{y\in M|d(x,y)<\varepsilon\} $

$K_{\varepsilon}(x):= \{y\in M|d(x,y)\leq \varepsilon\} $

$\overline{U_{\varepsilon}(x)} \subseteq K_{\varepsilon}(x)$

The usual example that equality does not hold is the discrete metric. I need to show that we can construct a counterexample in the set

$M:=S^1\cup \{(x,0)|0\leq x\leq 1\}$

with

$S^{n-1}:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n| \hspace{3pt} ||x||_2= 1\} $

Lets take $(1,0)\in M$. For $\varepsilon =1$ I see that $(1,0)\in K_{\varepsilon}(1)$ and I see that $(1,0)\notin U_{\varepsilon}(1)$ but how can I see that $(1,0)\notin \overline{U_{\varepsilon}(1)}$?

Furthermore do you see why $M$ is constructed this way?

[image]

Comment: Remember that your ultimate goal is to show that $\overline{U_{\varepsilon}(1)} \neq K_{\varepsilon}(1)$.  To do this, you don't need to show that $(1,0) \not\in \overline{U_{\varepsilon}(1)}$.  You just need to find SOME point in $K_{\varepsilon}(1)$ that is not in $\overline{U_{\varepsilon}(1)}$.  Are there any other such points for which this is more obviously the case?

Comment: I have uploaded my picture for $M$. $(1,0)$ is here B. The only other significant point to me is $(0,0)$ but I don't see what to do with it?

Comment: Ah, forgive me; I misunderstood the notation.  Consider $O =(0,0)$ as your center instead of $(1,0)$.  What is $U_1(O)$?  What is $K_1(O)$?

Comment: Both of them are $0$? So $O$ is in both?

Comment: Wait, If I take $\varepsilon =0$ I get for the first $\emptyset$ and for the second $(0,0)$. Is this right?

Comment: @Averroes2: $\epsilon$ is required to be positive. Take $\epsilon=1$, as **ArbitraryRenaissance** suggested.

Comment: $U_1(O)$ is the set of all points whose distance from $O$ is less than $1$.  This will contain all of the points $(x,0)$ for $0\leq x < 1$, but it will contain none of $S^1$, since all such points have distance $1$.  But then $K_1(O)$ will contain all of $S_1$ since it includes points whose distance from $O$ is less than or equal to $1$.

Comment: OK thanks, but now we have shown that $U_1(O)\neq K_1(O)$. But how can I know that $\overline{U_1(O)}$ does not contain $S_1$?

Comment: By the way, make sure you understand the notation being used.  $U_\varepsilon$ takes in points, but in your description, you have $U_\varepsilon(1)$, which doesn't make sense because $1$ isn't a point.

Comment: As for why $\overline{U_1(O)}$ doesn't contain $S_1$, all you need to do is construct a closed set containing $U_1(O)$ but not all of $S_1$.

Comment: This would be $A:=\{(x_1, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | 0 \leq x_1 \leq 1\}$. So is it right to say: $U_1(O)\subseteq A \Rightarrow \overline{U_1(O)}\subseteq A =(M\backslash S^1)\cap (1,0) \subset M =K_1(O)$

Comment: As a matter of fact, $A = \overline{U_1(O)}$ (which shouldn't be too surprising, since $A$ is just $U_1(O)$ plus one point).  The only thing not quite right is that you want $A = (M \setminus S^1) \cup (1,0)$, not $\cap$.

Comment: You're right, thanks for your help!